# JPA persist object in a ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity-relationship

I have a company/employee `@OneToMany` relation in my database defined as:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long id;
   @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="companyid")
   Company company;
   ....
}

@Entity
public class Company {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

...
}
```

Now I am adding a newly created employee to a detached company. The code I use is something like:

```
Company company = em1.find(Company.class, 555L);
em1.close();

EntityTransaction et = em2.getTransaction();
et.begin();
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.company = company;
em2.persist(employee);
et.close();
```

Will this work ok?
Is hibernate going to merge the company into the 2nd EntityManager or just use its id and persist the employee object?
Might hibernate somehow duplicate my company object or throw an exception saying that a company with the same id already exists in the DB?

Comment: Worth mentioning that doing public field setting (employee.company = company) provides minimal mechanisms for a persistence solution to know that the field has changed; better to use a setter so any implementation will be happy.

Answer (score 9):

- In the described case `Company`'s `id` will be used when persisting `Employee` object, but `Company` itself will not be merged (note that `Employee` is the owning side of the relationship)
- If `Company` is transient rather than detached, you will get "object references an unsaved transient instance" error
- If `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` is used, you will get "detached entity passed to persist" error.

From JPA Specification:

> If X is a managed entity, it is
>   synchronized to the database.
>
> - For
>     all entities Y referenced by a
>     relationship from X, if the
>     relationship to Y has been annotated
>     with the cascade element value
>     cascade=PERSIST or cascade= ALL, the
>     persist operation is applied to Y.
> - For any entity Y referenced by a
>     relationship from X, where the
>     relationship to Y has not been
>     annotated with the cascade element
>     value cascade=PERSIST or cascade= ALL:
>
>   - If Y is new or removed, an
>       IllegalStateException will be thrown
>       by the flush operation (and the
>       transaction marked for rollback) or
>       the transaction commit will fail.
>   - If
>       Y is detached, the semantics depend
>       upon the ownership of the
>       relationship. **If X owns the
>       relationship, any changes to the
>       relationship are synchronized with the
>       database;** otherwise, if Y owns the
>       relationships, the behavior is
>       undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much axtavt. The code does work ok (exactly as you said). We wanted to be sure we are following the JPA rules and wont run into problems with some untested situations. Now we are. Thanks again!